# svnsync: Revision being currently copied, last merged revision, and destination HEAD are inconsistent

Tags: svn, synchronization, repository, svnsync

I run the following command:

```
svnsync synchronize svn://www.example.com/repos
svnsync: Revision being currently copied (19931), last merged revision (19929), and destination HEAD (19931) are inconsistent; have you committed to the destination without using svnsync?
```

And then I run it again 30 seconds later:

```
svnsync synchronize svn://www.example.com/repos
svnsync: Revision being currently copied (20012), last merged revision (20010), and destination HEAD (20011) are inconsistent; have you committed to the destination without using svnsync?
```

I don't understand why, if its "blocked", are the numbers increasing?

I'm doing the above as root, and no jobs or processes are running (and root is the only user account).

Comment: "no jobs or processes are running": so you don't have a parrallel svnsync in the background? Did you try to dump your repo to revision 19931, and resync it?

Comment: I have the same, with creating new fresh copied repo. svn 1.9.5 r1770682 , svnsync with the same svn base version.

Answer (score 0):

For your process, when you use a svnadmin load the primary repository should be locked. This process checks if the last merged revision are equal for a sync to commence.